# Python, How to multi dict declaring variables function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to do like this.

```
def multiDecare(num = eval(input('Enter number of variables : '))):
    I = 0
    get_var = {}
    while I < num:
       e = 'var'+str(I)
       get_var.update(dict.fromkey(e))
    return get_var
```

result when print like :

```
 {'var1':'','var2':'''var3':'''var4':'''var5':''}
```

Comment: What about increment I variable?

Comment: `eval(input())`? don't do this. Use `int(input())`, it's safer! and don't put that as a default argument as it'll be executed exactly once.

Comment: More to the point... Please don't use a default parameter to capture user input! That's just destined to mess with every static analysis tool out there, not to mention making my eyes bleed

Comment: what is your desired output exactly?

Comment: `get_var = dict.fromkeys(("var{}".format(i) for i in range(1,num+1)),"")` does exactly that.

Comment: even shorter: `get_var = {'var{}'.format(x+1): '' for x in range(num)}`

Comment: @farsil: exactly. I didn't see your comment but came to the same conclusion! unless you have a very old version of python, because dict comps exist only since 2.7 IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because you're not incrementing `I`.

To avoid all that `while` stuff (everybody gets caught once in a `while`), you could use a `for`loop, but even better, you could create your dictionary in 1 line using a gen-comprehension inside `from_keys`

```
def multiDeclare(num):
  return dict.fromkeys(("var{}".format(i) for i in range(1,num+1)),"")
```

or with dict comprehension:

```
  return  {"var{}".format(i+1):"" for i in range(num)}
```

with `num == 5`, the function returns:

```
{'var5': '', 'var4': '', 'var2': '', 'var1': '', 'var3': ''}
```

Aside:

- don't use `eval(input(""))`, it's unsafe and in that case `int(input(""))` does the same thing
- don't pass function calls as default parameters, only values (immutable is best).